# Обмен информацией с чужим Приложением

Tags: android

Есть множество хороших приложений (контроль за состоянием здоровья, ведением здорового образа жизни), выполняющих похожие функции.
Некоторые из них хорошо дополняют друг друга.
Например планирование, ведение дневника и последующий контроль для

1. физической активности (Приложение 1) и
2. диетой и графиком приема пищи (Приложение 2).

Необходимо создать Приложение 3, которое будет являться надстройкой над Приложениями 1 и 2.
Приложение 3 должно уметь взаимодействовать с Приложениями 1 и 2.
А именно передавать им информацию и получать от них информацию.

Как правильно сформулировать требования к Приложениям 1 и 2, чтобы они допускали такой обмен информацией?
Как узнать позволяет или нет конкретное Приложение такой обмен?

Answer (score 0):

"Как правильно сформулировать требования к Приложениям 1 и 2, чтобы они допускали такой обмен информацией?" - так и формулируйте: приложение должно обеспечивать обмен информацией с другимим приложениями в виде/по протоколу/с помощью .... Главное, чтобы это было одинаково с обоих взаимодействующих сторон.

"Как узнать позволяет или нет конкретное Приложение такой обмен?" - из документации (справки) к приложению. Или по менюхам полазить, по форумам.

Кроме протокола обмена, должен быть согласован и объём и содержание передаваемой информации.

К примеру, на первый взгляд, упомянутые Вами приложения связывает одно - количество энергии (в калориях, чтоб понятней было). С одной стороны, усвоенной с пищей энергии, а с другой стороны - истраченной энергии на физическую активность. Можно использовать формат JSON. Поля: дата; кол-во энергии. Информация может сохраняться в файл или поститься по HTTP. Таким образом, приложение должно уметь сохранять (передавать) свою информацию описанным образом, а так же считывать (принимать) такую информацию.

Comment: Возможно я нечетко сформулировал. Приложение 1 и Приложение 2 уже существуют, они кем-то прекрасно написаны и выложены на Google Play. Чтобы обмениваться данными с ними нужно обязательно устанавливать контакт с разработчиком и получать от него разрешение?

Comment: Если приложения не предусматривают такого обмена информацией, то да, других вариантов нет.

Comment: Но это вопрос не для этого сайта. Вот если бы Вы сами хотели такое запрограммировать... А Вы хотите смотреть футбол по телеку :-(

Comment: Конкретный пример. Приложение 1 - это Strava (пользуюсь им уже 8 лет). Предусматривает оно или нет обмен информацией с другими Приложениями? Вдруг знаете... А футбол любит смотреть мой сын... . Я нет.

Comment: Судя по названию, стравой должно быть приложение № 2. Но я не знаю, к сожалению. По существу помочь не могу.

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.strava

Comment: Более 50 миллионов скачиваний...

Comment: ??? По чешски "страва" - диета. По белорусски, по украински - блюдо.  Ближе к жратве.

Comment: У Вас кроме этих двух приложений должно быть что-то вроде заметок или блокнота. Напишите себе: "Меньше жрать. Больше двигаться". Открывайте и перечитывайте это пять раз в день. И никакие приложения не нужны. А Вы, небось, ещё и деньги за эту "Страву" платите?